# how to namespace jquery to be used throughout my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces

in my script below, I use javascript to load jquery dynamically first. Once loaded, I want to namespace jquery's `$` so that I may use another name for it throughout my site. For instance, instead of calling `$('body').` , I want to call `MYNAMESPACE('body')`. But I can't get the namaspacing done correctly. Please help me on that part. Thanks..

```
(function () {

    function loadScript(url, callback) {

        var script = document.createElement("script")
        script.type = "text/javascript";

        if (script.readyState) { //IE
            script.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (script.readyState == "loaded" || script.readyState == "complete") {
                    script.onreadystatechange = null;
                    callback();
                }
            };
        } else { //Others
            script.onload = function () {
                callback();
            };
        }

        script.src = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    }

    loadScript("/plugins/system/conversekit/js/jquery.js", function () {

         //jQuery loaded
         alert('jquery loaded');
        var cKit = (function($){


            var loadScripts = function(){
                var jq = $.noConflict();
                return jq;
            }
            return {
                ConversekitJs : loadScripts// I expect this to return namespaced jquery
            };
        }

        })(jQuery);
            var js = cKit.ConversekitJs(); //function call

             //so that I may use jq instead of $ or jQuery
            js('body').css('background-color', '#ff0000');


    });


})();
```

EDIT based on answer suggested by R.J:

```
 var myNameSpace = jQuery.noConflict();

       (function(myNameSpace) {

          //Use your namespace
          myNameSpace('body').css('background-color', '#ff0000');//works
          myNameSpace.getScript("/js/events.js");//in this file myNameSpace has no effect..

       })(myNameSpace)
```

In events.js

```
 myNameSpace('body').css('background-color', '#ff0000');//doesn't work
```

But if I add var `myNameSpace = jQuery.noConflict();` on top of the page it would work..This is what I want to avoid. Instead of declaring this in each page, I would like to define once in top level.

Comment: What is ConversekitJs?

Comment: namespace that I gave...but it's done wrongly..pls correct it

Comment: You can not return cKit from callback

Comment: Please share the script inside `events.js` which trying to access namespace

Comment: in events.js this is want I'm doing... myNameSpace('body').css('background-color', '#ff0000');

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) with [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

```
var myNameSpace = jQuery.noConflict();

   (function(myNameSpace) {

      //Use your namespace
      myNameSpace('body').css('background-color', '#ff0000');

   })(myNameSpace)
```

Comment: say that I include myNameSpace.getScript("/js/events.js"); inside the IIFE..how can I use myNameSpace there in that file instead of $..that's my concern

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you would have to edit the jQuery source code somewhat.

```
/*!
 * jQuery library
 */

( function( global, factory ) {
  ...
})(window);

var myNamespace = myNamespace || {};
myNamespace.$ = myNamespace.jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

This should give you the `jquery` function or the `$` shortcut under your own namespace.